# How parse text of tag html

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I get from request this:

> In studio il corteggiatore ha il suo bel daffare per difendersi dalle accuse di Sabrina. E non solo le sue...<\/p>\r\n\t\t\t03\/11\/2017<\/date>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t

but I need to get only this:

> In studio il corteggiatore ha il suo bel daffare per difendersi dalle accuse di Sabrina. E non solo le sue...

This is my code:

```
try {
      // Connect to the web site
      Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://myapi.com").ignoreContentType(true).get();

      Elements img = document.select("p");

      for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++) {
            imgSrc = img.get(i);
            imgSrc2 = String.valueOf(imgSrc.text());



            System.out.println("resultTITLE:" + imgSrc2);
      }

  } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I do this? I am new with jsoup.

Comment: If you know you always want the text before the first `<\\/p>` and there are no other HTML tags before that, you can use `String.indexOf()`.

Comment: yes i want always the text before <\\/p>...how can i do it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The current code does not compile because there is no class and several variables have no declaration. Also, I do not understand how the code given relates to the question you ask.

Comment: with String.indexOf() can i say:"take all letters before <\\/p>"?

Comment: I suggest you read the String documentation. `String.indexOf()` can find the location of the `<`. You will need to find another method that gets the substring that you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code:-

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return result;
}
```